# Magento 2.3 Mysql Showing Upgrade Compilation Error

Tags: magento2, database

When i run php bin/magento setup:upgrade in cmd, then i'm getting this error. anyone can help me, why this error is showing ? website is working fine but i want to fix this error. Plz help if someone know about this. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Open the Database**

Go to the Table **Catalog_category_entity_text** and go to Indexes option and **remove the Index from Value Id.**

Hope This will help you!!

Comment: I'm running query but getting this error #1091 - Can't DROP INDEX `value_id`; check that it exists

Comment: drop all other indexes and set indexes for value_id as primary